# Cakephp not destroying session at browser close

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies

so my problem is that whenever i log in to the site using the Auth in cakephp and close it, it still brings me up to the index page of the site. i really don't know why cakephp does this, even if i close all the browser in my desktop and when i log in to the site, it still brings me to the index page which should be the log in page.

i tried doing this site [cakephp-cookie-lifteime](http://kodegeek.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/cakephp-cookie-lifetime-issue/)
but still nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

It is not issue of cake php or your server. Model browsers are not destroy session after browser closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in cakephp when you the close browser the session does not clear. You can update the following code in `core.php` file in `app/config` folder.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'cookie' => 'my_app',
    'cookieTimeout' => 0,
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'timeout' => 60 //1 hr
));
```

It may take some time to take effect on the local server. Please add this code and check in server and other pc.